# Как удалить ключ с реестра в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, реестр

Как удалить с реестра вот это ключ средствами Delphi

```
reg := TRegistry.Create;
reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', true);
reg.WriteString('Clock', 'C:\Windows\System32\Clock.exe');
reg.CloseKey;
reg.Free;
```

Мне надо удалить ключ после ввода пароля, вот так

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
reg:Tregistry;
begin
if edit1.Text='123' then
// Здесь нужно удалить ключ, помогите, пожалуйста?
PostMessage(FindWindow(Nil, 'ProgramBonus.exe'), WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
end;
end.
```

Comment: **из** реестра

ах, это ж опять очередной виртуал LogDog

Answer (score 1):

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create;
try
  Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if Reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', False)
    and Reg.ValueExists('Clock')
  then
    Reg.DeleteValue('Clock');
finally
  Reg.Free;
end;
```

Если ветка `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` не существует или у нас нет прав на доступ к ней, то удалить мы там ничего не сможем. Если она не существует, то создавать ее из своего приложения вовсе ни к чему (второй параметр `False`), винде виднее что у нее там должно быть в реестре. Если значение `Clock` не существует, то удалять нечего. Объект класса `TRegistry` удалится в любом случае, даже если при доступе к реестру возникнет непредвиденное исключение.

Answer (score 0):

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create;
Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
if Reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', true) then
  Reg.DeleteValue('Clock');
Reg.Free;
```

Comment: Вот это уже правильный вариант, правда дубликат моего...

Comment: Не дубликат, есть одна важная проверка.

Comment: У меня присутствует в коде не менее важная проверка:

     if (reg.ValueExists('Clock'))

Если она вернет false, то это будет означать, что открытие ключа либо не удалось, либо значения в ключе не существует.

Comment: Чепуха,

> будет означать, что открытие ключа либо не удалось

Нет такой проверки. В худшем случае сниппет успешно удалит ни в чем не повинное значение `HKLM\Clock`

Answer (score -1):

Вы наверняка имели ввиду не ключ, а значение, находящееся в ключе автозагрузки. Удалить нужное вам оттуда значение можно так:

```
reg := TRegistry.Create;
reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', true);
if(reg.ValueExists('Clock')) then
reg.DeleteValue('Clock');
reg.CloseKey;
reg.Free;
```

Comment: Прописатся, прописался в реестр, а удаляться не хочет, что делать ?

Comment: А мой, вышеприведенный код, что по-вашему делает?